# Django - Djangorestframework как исправить отображение в DEBUG=False?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста! Есть такая проблема.
Django DEBUG=True, все нормально отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставлю настройку на деплой DEBUG=False, пишу ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*',]:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может что пропустил?
Запускаю на локалхосте.
Браузер ругается (на пикче ниже видно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без дебага на продакшене нужно раздавать статику специально обученным под это сервером, например nginx

Comment: Да, я нашел уже) Спасибо! Изучаю вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Не очень сложно.

Чтобы заработали стили, можно собрать всю статику в одном месте, включая админские, необходимо сделать две вещи

1. Определить (если не определено) переменную `STATIC_ROOT` в файле с натройками `settings.py`. [документация на английском](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_ROOT)
2. Выполнить команду в окружении проекта `django`

   ```py
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```

После данных манипуляция все стили для всего проекта окажутся в одной папке, которая определена в пункте 1.

[Документация на английском](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)